# Vuex Typescript I am getting the error "Member 'someMutation' implicitly has an 'any' type." in the Component.ts file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am getting the error:

> "Member 'someMutation' implicitly has an 'any' type.".

This error appears in my Vue Component in `Component.ts` file for the mutation, received from Vuex store.

I have the following code in `Component.ts`:

```
@WithRender
@Component({
    components: { SomeChildComponent },
})
export default class Component extends Vue {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.someFunc(this.someComponentMethod);
        // ... some logic
    }
    @Mutation public someMutation;

    private someComponentMethod(str: string) {
        this.someMutation();
    }
}
```

Code in store for mutations:

```
const mutations: MutationTree<State> = {
    someMutation(state, name: string): void {
        state.prop = state.prop.filter((el: IEl): boolean => el.name !== name);
    },
};

const c = {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
};

const store = new Vuex.Store(c);
```

I tried some variants like `@Mutation public someMutation: void;` or `@Mutation public someMutation(s: string): void;`, but was not successful.

My intention is to solve the issue, not just to turn off the rule `NoImplicitAny` in `tslint.json` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the source of `someMutation`, the method takes a `string` argument called `name`, and it returns `void`, which is typed like this:

```
(name: string) => void
```

Since the property is automatically initialized by `vuex-class`, we can use the [definite assignment assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) to avoid the "no initializer" error.

```
!: (name: string) => void
^
```

The final result is:

```
@Mutation someMutation!: (name: string) => void
```

Comment: Tony, thank you very much for the answer! This solution is absolutely resolve my issue!) You are Typescript Guru! Thanks again!:)

Comment: @Vika No problem :)